# How do I interpret this equation of a line $ N^Tx=c $?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I apologize for the vague title, it's basically all I've been given in a lecture I'm trying to review.
$N$ is the normal to the line.

For some context that might help. It's in an algorithm about finding the closest point on a line to another point $p$.

The derivation goes as follows:
$$N^T(p + t\text{N}) = c $$
$$ \iff N^Tp + tN^TN = c$$
$$ \iff t = c - N^Tp$$
$$ \Rightarrow  p + tN = p + (c-N^Tp)N $$

I can't make sense of it though, hence the post.

Can someone figure out what vector $x$ is supposed to be and explain this equation $N^Tx = c $?

As I see it,
$x$ can't be along the line because that would mean $ c = 0 $ and the whole derivation doesn't make sense?

Thank you so much, been a long day and this confuses me a lot.

Comment: $x$ is a vector from the origin to any point on the line.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy thank you, I think I see, so N is for direction and c for the intercept?  Is c constant then?

Comment: Right, you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are working in two dimensions.

The line is *defined* to consist of all points $x$ satisfying $N^\top x = c$. Note that $c$ is a scalar, and $N$ and $x$ are both vectors. When $c=0$, this line is perpendicular to $N$ and goes through the origin, but in general when $c \ne 0$ the line does not go through the origin.

The derivation is making use of this fact (that may have already been established in your lecture):

> If $x^*$ is the closest point on the line $\{x : N^\top x = c\}$ to $p$, then $x^*-p$ is parallel to $N$.

Given this fact, this means we can write $x^*$ as $x^*=p+tN$ for some scalar $t$.

We have two facts:

- $x^*=p+tN$ (i.e. $x^*-p$ is parallel to $N$)
- $N^\top x^* = c$ (i.e. $x^*$ lies on the line).

By combining these two facts, we have $N^\top (p+tN)=c$ which is the first step in your post, and the subsequent steps solve for the value of $t$.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't make sense of $N^Tx = c$, when you say "If $c=0$ the line is perpendicular to $N$" I don't quite get it, isn't $N$ defined as being perpendicular to the line?

Comment: In 3D that would be the equation of a plane.

Comment: @oliver I think it would be best if you tried a few examples. Take $N=(1,0)$ and sketch out all $x$ satisfying $N^\top x = 0$. Then do the same for $N^\top x = 1$. Try both these things for other values of $N$ like $N=(1,1)$ or $N=(1,-1)$.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy thank you very much, this helped a lot because the equation of a plane I remember and understood (probably because I only learned it this single way).

Comment: @angryavian thank you very much for taking the time, I did that, and it worked surprisingly. Together with your follow up and Bobby Laspy's reminder of the plane which I worked through, I finally was able to get that equation, than you very much!